# How to draw plane partitions without lines separating cubes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I am trying to adapt the ''Plane partition'' [example](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/plane-partition/) by Jang Soo Kim  to draw plane partitions without lines in between the cubes. I have tried to do so by giving these lines the same color as the faces of the cube. That is, I replace ''draw=black'' by e.g. ''draw=yellow'' for the top face of a cube (see the MWE at the bottom of this question). This results in the plane partition below.

As one can see, there still remain thin lines separating the cubes in this plane partition. I have tried getting rid of these lines but have had no luck so far. The MWE leading to the plane partition is given below, can this be adapted so that the lines separating cubes are entirely removed?

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
% Three counters
\newcounter{x}
\newcounter{y}
\newcounter{z}

% The angles of x,y,z-axes
\newcommand\xaxis{210}
\newcommand\yaxis{-30}
\newcommand\zaxis{90}

% The top side of a cube
\newcommand\topside[3]{
  \fill[fill=yellow, draw=yellow,shift={(\xaxis:#1)},shift={(\yaxis:#2)},
  shift={(\zaxis:#3)}] (0,0) -- (30:1) -- (0,1) --(150:1)--(0,0);
}

% The left side of a cube
\newcommand\leftside[3]{
  \fill[fill=red, draw=red,shift={(\xaxis:#1)},shift={(\yaxis:#2)},
  shift={(\zaxis:#3)}] (0,0) -- (0,-1) -- (210:1) --(150:1)--(0,0);
}

% The right side of a cube
\newcommand\rightside[3]{
  \fill[fill=blue, draw=blue,shift={(\xaxis:#1)},shift={(\yaxis:#2)},
  shift={(\zaxis:#3)}] (0,0) -- (30:1) -- (-30:1) --(0,-1)--(0,0);
}

% The cube 
\newcommand\cube[3]{
  \topside{#1}{#2}{#3} \leftside{#1}{#2}{#3} \rightside{#1}{#2}{#3}
}

% Definition of \planepartition
% To draw the following plane partition, just write \planepartition{ {a, b, c}, {d,e} }.
%  a b c
%  d e
\newcommand\planepartition[1]{
 \setcounter{x}{-1}
  \foreach \a in {#1} {
    \addtocounter{x}{1}
    \setcounter{y}{-1}
    \foreach \b in \a {
      \addtocounter{y}{1}
      \setcounter{z}{-1}
      \foreach \c in {1,...,\b} {
        \addtocounter{z}{1}
        \cube{\value{x}}{\value{y}}{\value{z}}
      }
    }
  }
}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\planepartition{{5,3,2,2},{4,2,2,1},{2,1},{1}}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: First step: Remove the `draw`s altogether. If there are still lines to be seen they are residuals from the fills of the cubes behind. This would be a rendering or precision issue then. The easiest approach: Create separate commands that do not fill these sides. Though, I'd opt for a PGFkeys powered re-write. (And then there are new 3d options for TikZ that has been developed in the last 13 years.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I first made solution 2 and in the end I noticed there is also the very simple solution 1!

### Solution 1 (simple)

Just add `line width=0pt` to the three commands that draw the sides.

### Solution 2 (complicated)

Only draw the things that are visible.

#### Adaptations

- use `count=\x` etc. instead of counters in `foreach`
- `leftside` and `rightside` get height as fourth parameter
- `remember` some last variables
- save some variable for later use after the for loop with `\xdef`

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{tikz}

% The angles of x,y,z-axes
\newcommand\xaxis{210}
\newcommand\yaxis{-30}
\newcommand\zaxis{90}

% The top side of a cube
\newcommand\topside[3]{
    \fill[fill=yellow, draw=yellow, line width=0pt, shift={(\xaxis:#1)}, shift={(\yaxis:#2)},
    shift={(\zaxis:#3)}] (0,0) -- (30:1) -- (0,1) --(150:1) -- cycle;
}

% The left side of a cube
\newcommand\leftside[4]{
    \fill[fill=red, draw=red, line width=0pt, shift={(\xaxis:#1)}, shift={(\yaxis:#2)},
    shift={(\zaxis:#3)}] (0,0) -- (0,-#4) -- ++(150:1) --++ (0,#4) -- cycle;
}

% The right side of a cube
\newcommand{\rightside}[4]{
    % #1, #2, #3 = x, y, z
    % #4 = height
    \fill[fill=blue, draw=blue, line width=0pt, shift={(\xaxis:#1)}, shift={(\yaxis:#2)},
    shift={(\zaxis:#3)}] (0,0) -- (30:1) -- ++(0,-#4) --(0,-#4) -- cycle;
}

% Definition of \planepartition
% To draw the following plane partition, just write \planepartition{ {a, b, c}, {d,e} }.
%  a b c
%  d e
\newcommand{\planepartition}[1]{
    \def\lasty{0}
    \foreach \a [count=\x, remember=\a as \lasta, remember=\x as \lastx] in {#1} {
        \foreach \height [
            count=\y,
            remember=\height as \lastheight,
            remember=\y as \yy,
        ] in \a {
            % topside
            \topside{\x}{\y}{\height}
            
            % right side
            \ifnumless{\height}{\lastheight}{
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\h}{\lastheight-\height}
                \rightside{\x}{\yy}{\lastheight}{\h}
            }{}
            
            % save values for last right side
            \xdef\height{\height}
            \xdef\y{\y}
            
            % draw left sides
            \ifnumgreater{\lasty}{\y-1}{
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastlineheight}{{\lasta}[\y-1]}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\heightdiff}{int(\lastlineheight - \height)}
                \ifnumgreater{\heightdiff}{0}{
                    \leftside{\lastx}{\y}{\lastlineheight}{\heightdiff}
                }{}
            }{}
        }
        % draw last right side
        \rightside{\x}{\y}{\height}{\height}
        
        % draw left sides
        \ifnumgreater{\lasty}{\y}{
            \foreach \yi in {\y, ..., \lasty} {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastlineheight}{{\lasta}[\yi-1]}
                \ifnumless{\yi-1}{\y}{
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\currentlineheight}{{\a}[\yi-1]}
                }{
                    \def\currentlineheight{0}
                }
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\heightdiff}{int(\lastlineheight - \currentlineheight)}
                \ifnumgreater{\heightdiff}{0}{
                    \leftside{\lastx}{\yi}{\lastlineheight}{\heightdiff}
                }{}
            }
        }{}
        
        \xdef\lasty{\y}
        \xdef\a{\a}
        \xdef\x{\x}
    }
    
    % draw last left side
    \foreach \yi in {1, ..., \lasty} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastlineheight}{{\a}[\yi-1]}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\heightdiff}{int(\lastlineheight - 0)}
        \ifnumgreater{\heightdiff}{0}{
            \leftside{\x}{\yi}{\lastlineheight}{\heightdiff}
        }{}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \planepartition{{5,3,2,2},{4,2,2,1},{2,1},{1}}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Or just remove the dang `draw` options in the first place.

Comment: Removing the `draw` option or setting `draw=none` did not solve the problem for me.

Comment: I don't get a difference between `draw=none` or `line width=0pt` and a little bit of the fill from behind still peaks through. It looks like your viewer handles `line width=0pt` somewhat special. Maybe OP's viewer works the same.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes, it might be depending on the PDF viewer.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks a lot!